# Resource Rate of Victory Points?

Tags: company-of-heroes

In Company of Heroes Online, what is the rate that resources accumulate?  I.e. if a point is +3 manpower, what does that represent in terms of some amount per second, or per minute?

I am thinking for the sake of when is it worth building an observation post and how long it will be for the payoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall all rates are per minute.

Obs posts deliver more than just added manpower though: It is less easy for your opponent to take it over, so if you can spare the resources ("time, money, manpower") to build it, it is generally a good idea.

Comment: Rates are indeed per minute, and an observation post adds a 40% bonus. So for manpower points, you only make a loss, except for long games with lots of players in your team. For fuel and munitions, it's a tradeoff.